# sed reverse order label reading

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to use sed to parse a file and prints only the last `i` labels within a field. Each label is separate by a `.`.

If I select `i=3`, with a file that contains the following lines:

```
begin_text|label_n.label_n-1.other_labels.label3.label2.label1|end_text
BEGIN_TEXT|LABEL3.LABEL2.LABEL1|END_TEXT
Begin_Text|Label2.Label1|End_Text
```

I would like, if there are at least 3 labels, the output lines to be:

```
begin_text|label_n.label_n-1.other_labels.label3.label2.label1|end_text
BEGIN_TEXT|LABEL3.LABEL2.LABEL1|END_TEXT
```

Currently :

```
sed 's;\(^[^|]\+\)|.*\.\([^\.]\+\.[^\.]\+\.[^\.]\+\)|\([^|]\+$\);\1|\2|\3;' test.txt
```

produces:

```
begin_text|label3.label2.label1|end_text
BEGIN_TEXT|LABEL3.LABEL2.LABEL1|END_TEXT
Begin_Text|Label2.Label1|End_Text
```

and I do not get why a matching occurs for line 3. I also suppose ther eis a better way to do reverse order label reading.

Any comment/suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk will make the job easier.

```
awk 'split($2,a,".")>=i' FS="|" i=3 file

begin_text|label_n.label_n-1.other_labels.label3.label2.label1|end_text
BEGIN_TEXT|LABEL3.LABEL2.LABEL1|END_TEXT
```

#### Explanation

```
split(string, array, fieldsep)
split returns the number of elements created.
```